# Get data from array in nested json using Google Script

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, instagram

I need to fix a Google Script I've been working on. Basically, I have a json https://www.instagram.com/nike/?__a=1 that returns basic info about Nike's account on instagram. I have no problem retrieving data from objects such as "biography". But, when I try to retrieve nested objects (arrays) I'm doing something wrong because the results arrive duplicated (see attachment). Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
// the name of the sheet within your document
var sheetName = "Sheet1";
// the name of the Instagram account you want the follower count for
var instagramAccountName = "nike";

function insert() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(this.sheetName);
  var followers = [];
  var followers = captionArray(this.instagramAccountName);
  for(var i = 0 ; i < 3; i++) {
    sheet.appendRow([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd"), followers]);  
  };
}

function captionArray(username) {
  var i = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + username + "/?__a=1";
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    var caption = [];
    var caption = JSON.parse(response).graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges[i].node.edge_media_to_caption.edges[i].node.text;
    return caption;
  };
}
```

Comment: (There is no attachment). You should ensure that your code is properly formatted (read: the indentation level is such that it is useful for checking your code's organization, and identifies which statements are in which loops (aka visually defines "block scopes")). Also note that the positioning of your `return` statement means you never retrieve more than the 1st caption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is causing problems:

- You're using the same index (i) for both arrays, but the second have only one element.
- You just need to do one request.

This code works for me:

```
function captionArray(username) {
  var captions = [];
  var url = "https://www.instagram.com/nike/?__a=1";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText(); 

  var edges = JSON.parse(response).graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges;

  for(var i = 0, limit = edges.length; i < limit; i++) {
    captions.push(edges[i].node.edge_media_to_caption.edges[0].node.text); 
  }

  return captions; 
}
```

Comment: The first line in the function, `var i = 0;` seems unnecessary. Can you edit it out for the sake of clarity if you agree and the code runs without it okay?